# Using MIN() and COUNTIF() - Value either exceeds MIN() or not changing at all

Tags: excel

Attempting to create an attendance tracker. Cells B5 through B(undecided) will have a max value of 100%. The below formulas in code-blocks are being input into B5.

[image: Snippet of spreadsheet]

I have been messing with two formulas that I have gotten the closest to reaching my goals with:

`=MIN(100%,SUM(COUNTIF(C5:AH5,"y")+0.5%)+COUNTIF(C5:AH5,"ua")-5%)`

That one does not change the result from 100%. There are 7 "ua's" between C5 and I5 therefore the result should be 65% (100% - 35%). Instead it stays at 100%, unchanged.

Second approach is:

`=MIN(100,SUM(COUNTIF(C5:AH5,"y")+0.5)+COUNTIF(C5:AH5,"ua")-5)`

In this case, the value remains at 250% and does not change.

Unsure whats going on here. Is it my usage of COUNTIF() or MIN()? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but the first thing is that you would need a multiplication somewhere to count the number of ua's and subtract 5% each time:

```
=100%+COUNTIF(C5:AH5,"y")*0.5%+COUNTIF(C5:AH5,"ua")*-5%
```

This does give 65%, but I am sure there is more to this question - presumably you want to get a percentage of the number of possible attendances that are y's?

The second formula gives

```
min(100, +.5 + 7 -5)
```

which gives

```
min(100, 2.5)
```

which gives

```
2.5
```

which when expressed as a percentage gives

```
250%
```

Comment: "presumably you want to get a percentage of the number of possible attendances that are y's?"

B5 holds the total for Test. The total is the result of all y's and ua's in C5:AH5 and cannot exceed 100%. Then total C6:AH6 for Test2, C7:AH7 and so on. Example: Test2 total should be 95.5% in B6.

`=100%+COUNTIF(C5:AH5,"y")*0.5%+COUNTIF(C5:AH5,"ua")*-5%` This looks close to what I want, just need to figure out how to make it not exceed 100%.

Comment: Got it with `=MIN(100%,100%+COUNTIF(C5:AH5,"y")*0.5%+COUNTIF(C5:AH5,"ua")*-5%)`